# How to toggle class of multiple list items which displayed without *ngFor in Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to toggle active class in `<li>` list.
I don't want to use `*ngFor` to display the `<li>` items. 
I want to style the active(clicked) `<li>`.

```
  <ul class="table-filter">
              <li><span (click)="Filter('')" >All Test Result</span></li>
              <li><span (click)="Filter('pass')" >Pass Test Result</span></li>
              <li><span (click)="Filter('fail')" >Fail Test Result</span></li>
              <li><span (click)="Filter('skip')" >Skipped Test Result</span></li>
          </ul>   

Filter(innerText:any) {
    this.dataSource.filter = innerText.trim().toLowerCase();  
  }
```

Comment: where is your ngFor?

Comment: A little bit clarity would be great.

Comment: Its without ngFor. I need to displayed list items without ngFor

Comment: @Praveen how does it differ?

Comment: @MacleanPinto In all <li> function the parameter are different ex. 'skip', 'pass', 'fails' . If i will use ngFor how do i pass the different parameter inside the function name.

Comment: You say you don't want to use `ngFor`. If it can be done with `ngFor`, would you use it?

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle a variable in template:

```
<ul class="table-filter">
     <li>
        <span (click)="Filter(''); isOk=!isOk" 
             [ngClass]="isOk? 'success' : 'danger'">All Test Result
        </span>
     </li>              
</ul>
```

Or create a variable in TypeScript:

```
isOk: boolean = false;
clickEvent(){
    this.isOk = !this.isOk;       
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="table-filter">
    <li>
        <span (click)="Filter('')" 
              [ngClass]="isOk? 'success' : 'danger'">All Test Result
        </span>
    </li>              
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <ul class="heroes">
      <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
        [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
        (click)="onSelect(hero)">
        <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  heroes = HEROES;
  selectedHero: Hero;
  onSelect(hero: Hero) { this.selectedHero = hero; }
}
```

From angular documentation : https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2#style-the-selected-hero

Answer (score 0):

#### template

```
 <ul class="table-filter">
   <li><span (click)="toggleFilter('')" >All Test Result</span></li>
   <li><span [class.hidden]="hidden.pass" (click)="toggleFilter('pass')" >Pass Test Result</span></li>
   <li><span [class.hidden]="hidden.fail" (click)="toggleFilter('fail')" >Fail Test Result</span></li>
   <li><span [class.hidden]="hidden.skip" (click)="toggleFilter('skip')" >Skipped Test Result</span></li>
 </ul>
```

#### component

```
hidden = {
  pass: false, fail: false, skip: false
}

toggleFilter(key:string) {
  if(!this.hidden.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    this.hidden = {
      pass: false, fail: false, skip: false
    };
    return;
  }

  this.hidden[key] = !this.hidden[key];
}
```

#### stylesheet

```
.hidden { display: none }
```

working demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-52vcuj

Comment: I tried its not working, can you share the working link.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="table-filter">
    <li (click)="isClicked = !isClicked" [ngClass]="isClicked? 'active' : ' '"><span (click)="applyFilter('')" >All Test Result</span></li>
    <li  [ngClass]="{'active':status.pass == true, ' ':status.pass == false}"><span (click)="applyFilter('pass')" >Pass Test Result</span></li>
    <li  [ngClass]="{'active':status.fail == true, ' ':status.fail == false}"><span (click)="applyFilter('fail')" >Fail Test Result</span></li>
    <li  [ngClass]="{'active':status.skip == true, ' ':status.skip == false}"><span (click)="applyFilter('skip')" >Skipped Test Result</span></li>
</ul>

status:object = {};
applyFilter(innerText:any) {
    this.dataSource.filter = innerText.trim().toLowerCase();  
    this.status = {
        pass: false, fail: false, skip: false
    };
    this.status[innerText] = true;
    this.isClicked = false;
}
```